# Record Types for Opportunity Product object?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, opportunity-lineitem

It seems we are not allowed to create record types on the opportunity product object.  I have a use case where I would like to show different fields based on the product type selected.

Is there a workaround that can be done for this?  I've done some scouring online, but have not been able to find any viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, currently this feature is not available as per salesforce standard functionality.

If you need this functionality Please upvote the [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhisUAB/opportunity-products-record-types). Once we got the sufficient votes then it will be consider and available in the future releases.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share the workaround.

My Solution So, what I created was a custom object and created the bare minimum # of fields that my reps need to update that mirror the Opp Product fields and created a generic master record type Then, I created two process builders that-

1. Whenever an Opp Product of a certain type is created, it creates a matching custom object record. This same process builder also has the custom object continually referencing the Opp Product record. For added security, I created a boolean on the Opp Product that gets set to true to prevent any more custom object records being created. (Our org has code to refresh the opp products every four hours so this works for us)
2. I then created the same exact process builder but reversed it (minus new record creations). So, anytime you make a change to the custom object record, it will update the Opp Product record and reference where needed. As for the Owner and the Name standard fields I simply mapped over the Opp name and Opp owner. I then created a custom report type that was Opportunities with Opportunity Products with Custom Object (If you can't tell yet, I haven't been able to come up with a name for the object yet)

This is a great solution for my company as it allows us to even further analyze that area of our business. Hope this helps!

Comment: When you say "Opp Product of a certain type is created", you mean you have a picklist field or some field that you use to differentiate the product type?

What does the process builder process look like that is continually referencing the opp product record?